# Java GUI programming beginner tips

Tags: java

Im quite good with writing text based programs using Java and ill like to proceed to writing GUI programs and animations ive checked several youtube playlists and they dont seem do helpful so i would appreciate any tips on where to start.

Comment: How about Oracle's own Swing tutorials?

Comment: What kind of GUI are you interested in? Desktop or Web?

Comment: I can't get those people who downvote such beginner topics. IMHO good question. This isn't a question like 'please write function for me, while i do nothing'...

Comment: @Reborn yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Reborn And I don't get why newbies think that Stack Overflow is a place for asking about career advices or what they should learn/read. These questions are off-topic.

Comment: Get yourself some Widget tool as to be found in about any IDE for some language (probably Java in your case since you have experience with that, so maybe Netbeans?), draw some Widgets in it, maybe do a tutorial on that tool in that IDE, think of some program you want to write in order to learn and then learn by doing. Put how to do this and that into a search engine, look at the code and try to understand it. Ask on SO if you got specific problems like: "It says this and that error in that line of code, why?", together with the other things as found in http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Tom forums are created for a specific reason - ask for a HELP. As i said earlier i don't see anything 'outlaw' for asking that kind of question. Topic is clear, why not help?

Comment: @Reborn This is no forum and if you don't see why this question is off-topic, then you may want to spend some time in the help center (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and see off-topic questions point 4).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: IMHO, SO is for specific programming questions/problems.  This question would be better asked on something like Reddit (or just use Google).  And the question is too vague to answer as well.

Comment: Ok then, why just not to make some sort of branch and call it 'sandbox' or so, where all dev beginners were able to ask how to make a first step in IT industry?

Comment: @Reborn Ask that here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For desktop applications, You should start with Java [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/).

> Swing API is a set of extensible GUI Components to ease the
>   developer's life to create JAVA based Front End/GUI Applications.

There are some good tutorials, I would suggest the following:

[JavaTPoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing) and [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/)

After completing swing, you can move on to [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm).

> JavaFX is a set of graphics and media packages that enables developers
>   to design, create, test, debug, and deploy rich client applications
>   that operate consistently across diverse platforms.

For that, you may follow to begin with

[code.makery](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need to do Swing before JavaFX, JavaFX was intended to be a successor to Swing, and it doesn't require any knowledge of Swing. In saying that, it can never hurt to get more exposure to different GUI libraries.

Comment: @chatton You do not need to downvote it. I was just guiding him, I never mentioned that without swing he can't do JavaFX.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything! I think both Swing and JavaFX are good options.

Comment: @chatton You shouldn't upvote this off-topic answer either. It just suports OP in thinking that such questions are on-topic and welcome here (they aren't).

Answer (score -1):

Sounds as a great question, but not self explanatory. Before making assumptions just ask your self -

> Do I feel myself as Web developer or a Desktop(Core) developer?

From a prospective of Desktop developer - take a look at Swing - it allows to make GUI forms and etc. If you decide to learn web, then take a look at Vaadin (which is made on top of GWT, and easier to dive in)..

Both of them have simlar syntax, so it would be always easier re-qualify...

UPDATE: While you still decide where to go, see this humble example of [Vaadin Application](https://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/#!dashboard)